# openpyxl saves same BytesIO with different results in caller and callee

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to update an excel file in memory and save the results to a stream, but somehow the bytes in the caller are different from those in the callee.

This is the callee code (everything works fine inside this function, file opens without warnings in Excel):

```
def myExcelUpdateFunction(outb):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(outb)
    # ... I do some updates to the workbook
    wb.save(outb)
    # Test 1: This file below works just fine!
    wb.save(filename="test1.xlsx")
```

This is the caller code (this is the code that is not working properly as Excel complains that the file is damaged and it needs to repair it):

```
        try:
            with open("a.xlsx", 'rb') as fh:
                outfile = io.BytesIO(fh.read())
            myExcelUpdateFunction(outb)
            # Test 2: This file displays a warning in excel about the need to recover it
            outfile.seek(0)
            with open("test2.xlsx", "wb") as fh2:
                fh2.write(outfile.read())
```

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to do to avoid excel complaining the "test2.xlsx" file is damaged?

I can see the files are different in excel comparator:
[see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfxki.png)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It looks like you want to append "a.xlsx" to "test2.xlsx". I suspect this could all be done using just `openpxyl`

Comment: I am trying to update a "template" (not an actual excel template, it's just a regular excel file that has some values pre-populated)  in memory using the callee function

Comment: So why not update using openpyxl?

Comment: The code doesn't make a lot of sense but it looks like the problem could be reduced to the reading to and writing from the in-memory object. I assume there is a problem with encoding somewhere. You should be able to see this in the command line.